# Flow has no singularities

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Context: Let $M$ be a compact, connected, edgeless bidimensional differentiable manifold and let $f:\mathbb R\times M\to M$ be a flow of class $C^2$ in $M$.

What does it mean that a flow has no singularities? I understand that a vector field does not have singularities but I do not understand the flow... or is it that we can trivially associate a vector field with a flow?

Comment: Given a flow, you can define a vector field by $X(x) := \frac{d}{dt} f^t(x) |_{t=0}$. Given a vector field, you can find a flow by solving the differential equation $X \circ f^t = \frac{d}{dt} f^t$ and using Picard-Lindeloff.